# why anchor element does not follow div bottom margin and div width is not proper?

Tags: html, css

The anchor element should be below the div element as I have used bottom margin
but both the div and anchor are displayed in the same line also the width of div 
is only upto the length of paragraph. Please help me understand.

CSS Code:

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    border: 5px solid black;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #668284;
    margin-bottom: 50px;

}
#id1 {
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <p id="id1">Welcome to the group</p>
        </div>
        <a href="yahoo.com">Yureka</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Some of your CSS is invalid, ex `width= 500px` maybe start by validating your code for syntax issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is because of position:fixed which you have set on your div

1.anchor  is showing before the div because your div is positioned fixed. fixed-position elements are independent of all others and are not part of the document flow and are relative to the view port or browser's window.
2.paragraph is taking full width of div is because P tag in html is a block level element ,block level elements take full width of parent and dont leave space for any other element.

solution:
1.if you want the anchor tag below div just remove position absolute from the div
2.if you want p tag not to take full width of the div just set it to display:inline-block

below is working example of solutions suggested

```css
div {
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #668284;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#id1 {
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="id1">Welcome to the group</p>
</div>

<a href="yahoo.com">Yureka</a>
</body>
```

Comment: in above answer you have not set any display properties to selector id1 but  paragraph is not taking full width of div. Please explain.

Comment: if you see the above example paragraph is taking full width of its parent which is div width is set to 500px, if you will remove that width of div both paragraph and div will take full 100% width of the page.

Comment: And div is itself a block element if you see by default its display is set block because of that even if you set width on div which is 500px in this case the area after the div is left blank and anchor tag comes on next line because as i mentioned in the answer block elements dont allow any other element in same line with them ,if you want a tag after div, make div display:inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give folowing css for the anchor "a" tag

`a{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 80px;
}`

In which DIV element you have assigned position:fixed, margin-bottom property will not accept.